# Query for all of a specific record where its related resource all have the same value for a single attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :memberships

# included columns
# id: integer

---------------------

Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

# included columns
# user_id: integer
# active: boolean
```

I'd like to be able to grab all users where all their memberships have 'active = false' in a single query. So far the best that I've been able to come up with is:

```
#grab possibles
users = User.joins(:memberships).where('memberships.active = false')
#select ones that satisfy condition
users.select{ |user| user.memberships.pluck(&:active).uniq == [false] }
```

which is not that great since I have to use ruby to pluck out the valid ones.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick:

```
users_with_active_membership = User.joins(:memberships).where(memberships: { active: true })
users = User.where( 'users.id NOT IN (?)', users_with_active_membership.pluck(:id) )
```

I am not sure of the result but I expect it to be 2 nested queries, one selecting the User ids having an active membership, the other query to select the User not in this previous ids list.

I can't test it since I don't have an environment with these relationships. Can you try it and post the SQL query generated? (add `.to_sql` to see it)

Another way, I don't know which could be the most efficient:

```
User.where( 'users.id NOT IN (?)', Membership.where(active: true).group(:user_id).pluck(:user_id) )
```

Comment: This is a great shot but still fires off two queries. The goal would be to do this in a single query joining and comparing values without having to do a subquery. I suspect using 'having' and 'not in' with aliasing might be the trick. I changed the above question description to use 'pluck' for the small optimization rather than using map. Thanks for the answer!